# Ho do we get Moment Do format in Luxon

Tags: datetime, momentjs, luxon

Moment Do => 1st, 2nd

cant see luxon doesn't provide this format. any suggestion or findings?

Comment: I fear that it's not possible to get this format natively in Luxon, see [this issue](https://github.com/moment/luxon/issues/264) where the maintainer states: _unfortunately, the Intl library on which Luxon depends doesn't have support for ordinals._

Comment: @VincenzoC Thanks, yes true. I googled and looked into Luxon api's but cant find out. seems like they dont support it for now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no in-built support in luxon for that, but you can write your custom logic something like below.

```js
// Import the DateTime class from Luxon
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

// Function to add ordinal suffix to day number
function addOrdinal(number) {
  const suffixes = ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'];
  const v = number % 100;
  return number + (suffixes[(v - 20) % 10] || suffixes[v] || suffixes[0]);
}

const date = DateTime.local(2023, 1, 1);

// Format the date as "1st Jan"
const formattedDate = `${addOrdinal(date.day)} ${date.toFormat('LLL')}`;

console.log(formattedDate); // Output: 1st Jan
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/luxon@1.3.2/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
```